# Guice synthetic methods warning

Tags: java, jpa, aop, guice, shiro

We are having Guice and its AOP support. We have two 3d party modules which use the AOP support: Shiro and the Guice's JPA module. As a result Guice complains that "The method may be intercepted twice". 
My question is how can I avoid such behavior: I probably do not need to intercept synthetic methods at all.

If the modules were ours we could just add a Matcher which filters out all synthetic methods (like it says [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=640)) but the problem is these are 3d party modules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way I could find is the following: just override the bindInterceptor methods like this.

Matcher:

```
public final class NoSyntheticMethodMatcher extends AbstractMatcher<Method> {
    public static final NoSyntheticMethodMatcher INSTANCE = new NoSyntheticMethodMatcher();
    private NoSyntheticMethodMatcher() {}

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Method method) {
        return !method.isSynthetic();
    }
}
```

The bindInterceptor method:

```
@Override
protected void bindInterceptor(Matcher<? super Class<?>> classMatcher, Matcher<? super Method> methodMatcher, MethodInterceptor... interceptors) {
    super.bindInterceptor(classMatcher, NoSyntheticMethodMatcher.INSTANCE.and(methodMatcher), interceptors);
}
```

But the solution doesn't always work. Like in my case, the target JpaPersistModule is final and the only way I could override the method is to copy pasted the implementation.